# NGINX - unificar configuración para http y https

Tags: linux, apache, servidor, nginx, servicio

Tengo esta configuración para un proyecto con PHP7, esta configuración funciona pero como podeis ver tengo el bloque duplicado para http y https, hay forma de unificar esto? He probado a eliminar el primer bloque y dejar el segundo entero con la configuración de

```
        #listen 80; <== activando esto, da error
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name miserver.dominio.com;
        ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/certs/test_wildcard_2020.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/test_wildcard_2020.key;



server {
        listen 80;
    server_name miserver.dominio.com;

    root /var/www/html/site1/test1;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 505 /500.html;

    location = /404.html {
                root /var/www/html/errors;
                internal;
    }


    location = /500.html {
                root /var/www/html/errors;
                internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}


server {
        #listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name miserver.dominio.com;
        ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/certs/test_wildcard_2020.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/test_wildcard_2020.key;

    root /var/www/html/site1/test1;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }


    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 505 /500.html;

    location = /404.html {
                root /var/www/html/errors;
                internal;
    }

    location = /500.html {
                root /var/www/html/errors;
                internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

intenta de esta forma y deja los certificados de ssl al final del objeto server, usa `sudo nginx -t` para que te diga si tienes errores antes que reinicies el nginx

```
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name .miserver.dominio.com;
root "/var/www/html/site1/test1";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , a funcionado a la primera.